# Parse JSON to fetch all the details using Asynctask

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

```
{

  "response_code": 200,

  "debit": 3,


  "position": "Train has reached Destination and late by 5 minutes",

  "train": {

    "number": "12046",
    "name": "CDG NDLS SHTBDI"
  },

  "route": [
            {

"no": 1,

      "day": 0,

      "station": {
        "name": "CHANDIGARH",
        "code": "CDG"
      },
      "has_arrived": false,
      "has_departed": true,
      "distance": 0,
      "scharr": "Source",
      "schdep": "12:00",
      "actarr": "00:00",
      "actdep": "12:00",
      "scharr_date": "19 Nov 2015",
      "actarr_date": "19 Nov 2015",
      "latemin": 0
    },
    {
      "no": 2,
      "day": 0,
      "station": {
        "name": "AMBALA CANT JN",
        "code": "UMB"
      },
      "has_arrived": true,
      "has_departed": true,
      "distance": 67,
      "scharr": "12:40",
      "schdep": "12:42",
      "actarr": "12:40",
      "actdep": "12:42",
      "scharr_date": "19 Nov 2015",
      "actarr_date": "19 Nov 2015",
      "latemin": 0
    },
    {
      "no": 3,
      "day": 0,
      "station": {
        "name": "NEW DELHI",
        "code": "NDLS"
      },
      "has_arrived": true,
      "has_departed": false,
      "distance": 265,
      "scharr": "15:25",
      "schdep": "Destination",
      "actarr": "15:30",
      "actdep": "00:00",
      "scharr_date": "19 Nov 2015",
      "actarr_date": "19 Nov 2015",
      "latemin": 5
    }
  ]
}


public class TrainStatus {

    public static int responseCode;
    private int serialNo;
    private String scheduleArrival;
    private String actualArrival;
    public static String station;
    public static int debit;
    private String statusOfArrival;
    private boolean hasArrived;
    private boolean hasDeparted;
    private int latemin;
    private String actualArrivalDate;
    private String scheduleArrivalDate;
    public static String position;
    public  String name;

        public String getName()
            {
                return getName();
            }
        public void setName(String name)
            {
                this.name=name;
            }

        public boolean isHasArrived()
            {
                return hasArrived;
            }

        public void setHasArrived(boolean hasArrived)
            {
                this.hasArrived = hasArrived;
            }

        public boolean isHasDeparted()
            {
                return hasDeparted;
            }

        public void setHasDeparted(boolean hasDeparted)
            {
            this.hasDeparted = hasDeparted;
            }

        public int getLatemin()
        {
        return latemin;
        }

        public void setLatemin(int latemin) 
        {
        this.latemin = latemin;
        }

        public void setSerialNo(int serialNo)
        {
        this.serialNo = serialNo;
        }

        public String getScheduleArrival()
        {
        return scheduleArrival;
        }

        public void setScheduleArrival(String scheduleArrival) 
        {
        this.scheduleArrival = scheduleArrival;
        }

        public String getActualArrival()
        {
        return actualArrival;
        }

        public void setActualArrival(String actualArrival)
        {
        this.actualArrival = actualArrival;
        }

        public String getStation() 
        {

            return station;
        }        

        public void setStation(String station)
        {

            this.station = station;
        }

    public String getStatusOfArrival() 
        {
            return statusOfArrival;
        }

    public void setStatusOfArrival(String statusOfArrival)  
        {
            this.statusOfArrival = statusOfArrival;
        }

    public String getActualArrivalDate() 
        {
            return actualArrivalDate;
        }

    public void setActualArrivalDate(String actualArrivalDate) 
        {
            this.actualArrivalDate = actualArrivalDate;
        }

   public String getScheduleArrivalDate() 

        {

 return scheduleArrivalDate;

}

    public void setScheduleArrivalDate(String scheduleArrivalDate) 
       {
          this.scheduleArrivalDate = scheduleArrivalDate;
       }
}



public class TrainStatusParser {

    public static List<TrainStatus> parseFeed(String content){
        try
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
            List<TrainStatus> trainList = new ArrayList<>();
            TrainStatus.responseCode = jsonObject.getInt("response_code");
            TrainStatus.position = jsonObject.getString("position");
            TrainStatus.debit=jsonObject.getInt("debit");
            JSONArray route = jsonObject.getJSONArray("route");
             for(int i=0;i<route.length();i++)
             {
                JSONObject routeObject = route.getJSONObject(i);
                TrainStatus trainStatus = new TrainStatus();
                if (jsonObject.has("station"))
                {
                       JSONObject addressObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("station");
                       trainStatus.name=addressObject.getString("name");
                }
                trainStatus.setSerialNo(routeObject.getInt("no"));
                trainStatus.setScheduleArrival(routeObject.getString("scharr"));
                trainStatus.setActualArrival(routeObject.getString("actarr"));
                trainStatus.setStatusOfArrival(routeObject.getString("status"));
                trainStatus.setHasArrived(routeObject.getBoolean("has_arrived"));
                trainStatus.setHasDeparted(routeObject.getBoolean("has_departed"));
                trainStatus.setLatemin(routeObject.getInt("latemin"));
                trainStatus.setActualArrivalDate(routeObject.getString("actarr_date"));
                trainStatus.setScheduleArrivalDate(routeObject.getString("scharr_date"));
                trainList.add(trainStatus);
            }
            return trainList;

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is correctly fetched except station name

Comment: The Json parsing seems okay. But did you mean `TrainStatus.name=...` or `trainStatus.setName(...)` ? or is it right the way it is ? Do you have an error message ? If not, what is the value retrieved from the parsing ?

Comment: TrainStatus is a class where name is defined and error message is not there but station name is empty

Comment: btw by changing that if (jsonObject) to simple these two line i am getting JSONObject from_station = routeObject.getJSONObject("station");
                 TrainStatus.station = from_station.getString("name"); same station name in every list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this following code.

```
 for(int i=0;i<route.length();i++) {
            JSONObject routeObject = route.getJSONObject(i);
            TrainStatus trainStatus = new TrainStatus();

            JSONObject jsonObject_station = routeObject.getJSONObject("station");

            String stationname = jsonObject_station.getString("name");
            String code = jsonObject_station.getString("code");
            Log.d("checkvalue", "   " + stationname + "    " + code);

            trainStatus.setSerialNo(routeObject.getInt("no"));
            trainStatus.setScheduleArrival(routeObject.getString("scharr"));
            trainStatus.setActualArrival(routeObject.getString("actarr"));
            trainStatus.setStatusOfArrival(routeObject.getString("status"));
            trainStatus.setHasArrived(routeObject.getBoolean("has_arrived"));
            trainStatus.setHasDeparted(routeObject.getBoolean("has_departed"));
            trainStatus.setLatemin(routeObject.getInt("latemin"));
            trainStatus.setActualArrivalDate(routeObject.getString("actarr_date"));
            trainStatus.setScheduleArrivalDate(routeObject.getString("scharr_date"));
            trainList.add(trainStatus);
        }
```

Comment: you have to parse based `routeObject`, i hope this will help you

Comment: @SangamNayak it should wrk check carryfully,,,k no problem ,post your code how you parsed Stationname

Comment: @SangamNayak i changed yesterday ok, now you are saying that nothing changed....Check carefully.

Comment: Oh k k,did you changed  `if (jsonObject.has("station"))
                {
                       JSONObject addressObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("station");
                       trainStatus.name=addressObject.getString("name");
                }`  instance of use this code   `JSONObject jsonObject_station = routeObject.getJSONObject("station");

            String stationname = jsonObject_station.getString("name");
            String code = jsonObject_station.getString("code");`

Comment: create Setter and Getter Method inside your  `TrainStatus`  class for this two variable `public  String name,code;` 
  Then add the value like this  `trainStatus.setstation_name(jsonObject_station.getString("name"));
  trainStatus.setstation_code(jsonObject_station.getString("code"))`

Comment: can u give me ur email id so that i will send u  whole code

Answer (score 0):

Use a library from Google call [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)

Answer (score 0):

In your posted code for parsing each `route`, you have this:

```
            JSONObject routeObject = route.getJSONObject(i);
            TrainStatus trainStatus = new TrainStatus();
            if (jsonObject.has("station"))
            {
                   JSONObject addressObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("station");
                   trainStatus.name=addressObject.getString("name");
            }
```

Looks like a typo here is causing your problems. You're calling `jsonObject.has("station")` when you should instead be calling `routeObject.has("station")`. Similarly, inside the `if` statement you should change `jsonObject.getJSONObject("station")` to `routeObject.getJSONObject("station")`.

Comment: Same thing happening by changing to route object

Comment: same name has been set in the textview by changing from jsonObject to routeObject